# solving the differential equation$y'+\sin y+x \cos y+x=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation?

$$y'+\sin y+x \cos y+x=0.$$

Comment: Here's a hint I got by asking Mathematica: try the substitution $y=2\tan^{-1}(f(x))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$y'+\sin y+x \cos y+x=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}+\sin y=-x(1+\cos y)$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac1{1+\cos y}+\frac{\sin y}{1+\cos y}=-x$$

Using $\cos 2z=2\cos^2z-1,\sin2z=2\sin z\cos z,$
$$\frac12\sec^2\frac y2 \frac{dy}{dx}+\tan\frac y2=-x$$

$$\implies  \frac{d\left(\tan\frac y2\right)}{dx}+\tan\frac y2 \cdot1=-x$$

Multiplying either sides by the [Integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)   $e^{\int dx}=e^x,$
$$ e^x\cdot d\left(\tan\frac y2\right)+\tan\frac y2 \cdot e^xdx=-e^xxdx$$

so that the left hand side becomes $d\left(e^x\cdot\tan\frac y2\right)$

So, we have  $$d\left(e^x\cdot\tan\frac y2\right)=-e^xxdx$$

Now integrate

Comment: @Angel, could you pinpoint where you are stuck?

Comment: Excellent.Thanks.

Comment: @Angel, my pleasure.